# What was the original ending in "Vámonos con Pancho Villa"?

Tags: alternate-version, vamonos-con-pancho-villa

I've heard the original ending for [*Vámonos con Pancho Villa*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027240/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (Fernando de Fuentes, México, 1936) was changed.

- What was the original ending?
- Why was it changed?

If possible, I'd need sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer [here](http://cinemexicano.mty.itesm.mx/peliculas/vamonos.html):

> Vámonos con Pancho Villa was news again in 1973, when Filmoteca UNAM found a 16mm copy including an, until then, unknown ending. In that alternate ending, Pancho Villa comes back to get Tiburcio Maya and asks him to fight again with his army. When Tiburcio refuses, Villa kills him, his wife and his daughter, and takes his young son to the Revolution. It is not known if this ending was censored, but it is more likely that it was De Fuentes himself who decided to remove it, finding it unnecessary or too cruel. The movie was broadcasted on Mexican TV with this ending in 1982.

The alternate ending can be found on YouTube:

My humble opinion is that the original ending is way better. The alternate ending, though, adds yet another dimension to the already multidimensional Villa character.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) your own answer if you're satisfied with it.